# Mysql : get average grouped per week

Tags: mysql, group-by

Let's say I have a table like this:

```
ID    Type    Itemcount    DateTime 
1       2          4        2018-05-05
2       1          10       2019-09-09
3       2          4        2018-05-05
4       1          10       2019-09-09
```

How to get the average amount of items of type 1 to exist by the datetime (grouped per week)
and I should go for one year back?. What is the max amount of items?

My solution :

```
set @totalitemssAllTypes =  (SELECT count(Itemcount)
        FROM db_dev.products
        where Datetime >= '2018-06-12 00:10:00.000000');

    SELECT CONCAT(YEAR(Datetime ), '/',MONTH(Datetime ), '/', WEEK(Datetime )), (count(LotCount)/@totalitemssAllTypes )
            FROM db_dev.products
            where Datetime >= '2018-06-12 00:10:00.000000' and 
                         Type    = 1
            GROUP BY WEEK(Datetime);
```

Please help thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would use the `WEEK()` function to aggregate:

```
SELECT
    WEEK(DateTime) AS week,
    AVG(Itemcount) AS item_avg
FROM db_dev.products
WHERE
    Type = 1 AND
    DateTime >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 YEAR)
GROUP BY
    WEEK(DateTime);
```

It should be noted that `WEEK()` may not number the weeks from 1 onward starting with the earliest week.